# Delete Duplicates VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to erase duplicate rows starting from bottom, but it isnt working. It keeps two copies but deletes other duplicate items.

```
With wb_DST.Sheets(sWs_DST)
    lncheckduplicatescolumn = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    wb_DST.Sheets(sWs_DST).Range(("A13:A" & lncheckduplicatescolumn - 2 & ":" & "AW13:AW" & lncheckduplicatescolumn - 2)).Sort key1:=wb_DST.Sheets(sWs_DST).Range("A13:A" & lncheckduplicatescolumn - 2), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

    Dim row As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Set rng = wb_DST.Sheets(sWs_DST).Range("A13:A" & lncheckduplicatescolumn - 2)
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
            .cell.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End with
```

If Excel shows

```
Column A       Column B
A                 1
A                 2
A                 3
```

I want the code to retain the last row, and delete the ones above it.

The result should be

```
Column A            Column B
A                    3
```

Thanks,

Comment: Your code isn't deleting duplicates, it deletes a duplicate only if there's a second one above it.

Comment: what does this even mean? `It keeps two copies but deletes other duplicate items.` ... be very specific when describing problems.

Comment: `For Each cell In rng` works top to bottom, left to right.

Comment: variable name `LnCheckDuplicatesColumn` is easier to read

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I need the code to delete any duplicates. Right now it doesn't function correctly. I need the code to delete any duplicates, and keep the data from the bottom. An example is given above.

Comment: The last question may give more insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584262/finding-duplicates-row

Comment: the code shared earlier wasn't working for me either.

Comment: @PlamZ thats why I am arranging it in descending order first so I can regroup them together. But still code doesnt delete all of the them

Comment: this is no help `Right now it doesn't function correctly` ... don't even bother posting a statement like that in the future. ... i asked you to be specific and describe the problem in detail. ... this is also no help `But still code doesnt delete all of the them` .... you never mention which lines get deleted .... your description is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Work from the bottom up and loop until all 'higher' (i.e. in a row less than current) are removed.

```
dim dup as variant, r as long, lncheckduplicatescolumn as long
With wb_DST.Sheets(sWs_DST)
    lncheckduplicatescolumn = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    for r = lncheckduplicatescolumn  to 2 step -1
        dup = application.match(.cells(r, "A").value, .columns(1), 0)
        if dup < r then .rows(dup).delete
    next r
end with
```

This will take a few more cycles than is absolutely necessary but the operation is efficient enough that it should not make a significant difference.

Comment: This works great, however is too slow for large sets of data, what do u recommend??

Comment: That sounds like a new question as this appears to have answered your original question given the details you ave provided. It would depend on the actual data. I might try a dictionary object constructed from a variant array of the actual values. Calculation cycles and event handling can also slow things down but you can suspend both of those. You might try posting a new question based on my code with details of the actual data at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel).

Comment: I just did, apprecaite your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim x as integer
Dim y as string
Dim J as integer
Dim I as integer

x = activesheet.range("A" & Activesheet.range("A1").endxl.down).count 'This will count the total number of rows. 


for i = x to 2 'this should count backwards from bottom to top, since you have headers, stop at row 2
 y = Activesheet.range("A" & i).value 'places value in a variable
      For j = x - i - 1 to 1 'this is another loop, but it should start above the whatever the cell that Y got its value 
        if activesheet.range("a" & j).value = y then 'comparison
            'do what you need to delete the row
        end if

Next
Next
```

I think this will go start at the bottom, put that first value in a variable, and then will go through the rest of the list check the values to see if is compatible. The second for loop might need to be adjusted.

Comment: `for i = x to 2` needs to be `for i = x to 2 STEP -1` and all of the vars for rows should be Long, not Integer.

Answer (score 0):

not a pretty answer - but from what it looks like, you should be ending up with the last and first occurrence of the duplicate:

```
 Column A    Column B
 A           1
 A           3
```

To patch your answer (there are more elegant ways), you could find the last row again after the loop is finished and check for one last duplicate:

```
 For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
        .cell.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
 Next
```

redefine your last row

```
 lncheckduplicatescolumn = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
```

and check for one more duplicate

```
 If Range("A" & lncheckduplicatescolumn).Value = Range("A" & lncheckduplicatescolumn).Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
    .cell.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
 End If
```